# Port a Python application to the Google Earth Engine?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I have a Python application used to extract urban area, and I want port this application into the Google Earth Engine, so this application can work on a large scale. But I don't know how to do this, are there some tools, or is the only way is to translate it to JavaScript?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [ Tour ], which explains how our "Focused question / Best answer" model operates. Unfortunately,  this is neither a GIS-centric question nor focused. Rewriting a massive volume of code is not a trivial task; if you haven't tried porting a small application, you really ought not try with a large one first.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not you can translate your Python application depends on what the application is specifically doing. In general, to take advantage of the scaling features of Earth Engine, you will need to translate the image processing algorithmic portions of your application into [Earth Engine objects and methods](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs).

Earth Engine has both Javascript and Python APIs. For simple applications, shared with colleagues that also have access to Earth Engine, you can use the Javascript API and the web-based [Earth Engine Code Editor](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/playground). For public websites, you can use the [Python API](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/python_install) and any Python web framework. There are a [few simple examples](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/app_engine_intro) shown in the documentation to get you started, but website development skills will be needed.